# Shopify Api working with PHP

Tags: php, shopify

I am working with Shopify Webhook for order fulfillment(in PHP) now i want the payment details of "Information from the gateway" which are available in the shopify admin but not showing in Webhook details so anyone can please give any solution for this. following is the screenshot of details which i want to get in order.

These following are details which I want when any new order is confirmed:

1) Authorization key

2) Name on Credit card

3) Exp month

4) Exp year

[details which i want to get in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLBrW.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this information you needs to use following shopify method

```
GET /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json
```

And following response you get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "id": 179259969,
      "order_id": 450789469,
      "amount": "209.00",
      "kind": "refund",
      "gateway": "bogus",
      "status": "success",
      "message": null,
      "created_at": "2005-08-05T12:59:12-04:00",
      "test": false,
      "authorization": "authorization-key",
      "currency": "USD",
      "location_id": null,
      "user_id": null,
      "parent_id": null,
      "device_id": null,
      "receipt": {},
      "error_code": null,
      "source_name": "web"
    },
    {
      "id": 389404469,
      "order_id": 450789469,
      "amount": "409.94",
      "kind": "authorization",
      "gateway": "bogus",
      "status": "success",
      "message": null,
      "created_at": "2005-08-01T11:57:11-04:00",
      "test": false,
      "authorization": "authorization-key",
      "currency": "USD",
      "location_id": null,
      "user_id": null,
      "parent_id": null,
      "device_id": null,
      "receipt": {
        "testcase": true,
        "authorization": "123456"
      },
      "error_code": null,
      "source_name": "web",
      "payment_details": {
        "credit_card_bin": null,
        "avs_result_code": null,
        "cvv_result_code": null,
        "credit_card_number": "•••• •••• •••• 4242",
        "credit_card_company": "Visa"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 801038806,
      "order_id": 450789469,
      "amount": "250.94",
      "kind": "capture",
      "gateway": "bogus",
      "status": "success",
      "message": null,
      "created_at": "2005-08-05T10:22:51-04:00",
      "test": false,
      "authorization": "authorization-key",
      "currency": "USD",
      "location_id": null,
      "user_id": null,
      "parent_id": null,
      "device_id": null,
      "receipt": {},
      "error_code": null,
      "source_name": "web"
    }
  ]
}
```

And you want to more details than please refer the below link:

```
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/transaction
```